# How can I get user input in java script and display this input on page?

Tags: javascript

I am new to java and am trying to create a game that simulates hangman. I am trying to get the letters from the user after they input on keyboard. However, when I type something it doesn't make any difference, it doesn't output whether it is correct or incorrect. I think I may not be using the event in my guessLetter() function correctly, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      var word = ['taco'];

      let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * word.length);
      let chosenWord = word[randNum];
      let underScore = [];

      let docUnderScore = document.getElementsByClassName('underScore');
      let docRightGuess = document.getElementsByClassName('rightGuess');
      let docWrongGuess = document.getElementsByClassName('wrongGuess');

      console.log(chosenWord); //lets grader cheat

      let generateUnderscore = () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < chosenWord.length; i++) {
          underScore.push('_');
        }
        return underScore;
      }


      document.onkeyup = function guessLetter(event) {
        let letter = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode || event.code).toLowerCase();

        if (chosenWord.indexOf(letter) > -1) {
          rightWord.push(letter);
          underScore[chosenWord.indexOf(letter)] = letter;
          docUnderScore[0].innerHTML = underScore.join(' ');
          docRightGuess[0].innerHTML = rightWord;
          if (underScore.join('') === chosenWord) {
            alert('CONGRATS! YOU WIN!!!');
          } else {
            wrongWord.push(letter);
            docWrongGuess[0].innerHTML = wrongWord;
          }
        }
        underScore[0].innerHTML = generateUnderscore().join(' ');

      }
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <h1> Hangman </h1>
  <div id="guesses">
    <div class="letter" id="letter" </div>
    </div>
</head>

<body>
</body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="underScore">_ _ _ _</div>
  <div class="rightGuess"> right guess </div>
  <div class="wrongGuess"> wrong guess </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Check out your console log. Your code is trying to use some undefined variables including rightWord and wrongWord (so either define them or use existing variables.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JS console, `ReferenceErrors` are being thrown as a result of the fact that the `rightWord` and `wrongWord` variables have not been defined.

Comment: I copied and pasted the code wrong, it still doesn't behave correctly.. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are writing the  in head tag why ? it doesn't shown in your web page , place the html tags within body.